# Сlick on a slide with the right mouse in Swiper.js

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    type: "custom",
});
```

https://codepen.io/maks778/pen/mdXKNxo

When you click on a slide with the right mouse button, the slide is switched, how to disable the action

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem has already been described in the [issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/5625) to Swiper 8. In your case, it might be worth trying to use the latest version of Swiper 7 (for example 7.4.1).

Below is your example, but with Swiper version 7.4.1:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        centeredSlides: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        type: "custom",
    });

    var appendNumber = 4;
    var prependNumber = 1;
    document
        .querySelector(".prepend-2-slides")
        .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            swiper.prependSlide([
                '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + --prependNumber + "</div>",
                '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + --prependNumber + "</div>",
            ]);
        });
    document
        .querySelector(".prepend-slide")
        .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            swiper.prependSlide(
                '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + --prependNumber + "</div>"
            );
        });
    document
        .querySelector(".append-slide")
        .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            swiper.appendSlide(
                '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + ++appendNumber + "</div>"
            );
        });
    document
        .querySelector(".append-2-slides")
        .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            swiper.appendSlide([
                '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + ++appendNumber + "</div>",
                '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide ' + ++appendNumber + "</div>",
            ]);
        });
```

```css
html,
        body {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background: #eee;
            font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #000;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .swiper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .swiper-slide {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            background: #fff;

            /* Center slide text vertically */
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .swiper-slide img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        .swiper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }
        .append-buttons {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .append-buttons button {
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid #007aff;
            color: #007aff;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 4px 10px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            margin: 0 10px;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div #swiperRef="" class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <a href="" class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</a>
        <a href="" class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</a>
        <a href="" class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</a>
        <a href="" class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</a>
        <a href="" class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

<p class="append-buttons">
    <button class="prepend-2-slides">Prepend 2 Slides</button>
    <button class="prepend-slide">Prepend Slide</button>
    <button class="append-slide">Append Slide</button>
    <button class="append-2-slides">Append 2 Slides</button>
</p>
```